# Other nouns formed by prepending _само_ to an action

Tags: существительные, composite-nouns

There are a number of nouns formed by prepending *само* to the action that that thing does that are very common: *самолет*, *самовар*. Other similar formations, like  *самодвижущийся*, are uncommon.

Are there other examples of this pattern where a synonym with this prefix exists, but is not the most common way to refer to a noun? Is there any distinction that can be drawn between types of nouns that prefer the *само*-prefixed synonym over those that don't (assuming both exist)?

Comment: The short answer is: yes. Why don't you simply open any Russian-Another_language dictionary and write out all the nouns that begin with _само-_? Shall we give you a complete list of them? This site discourages asking questions to make lists, that's why I vote to close the question.

Comment: @Yellow Sky Let me clarify in my question.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking about. What's the connection between _самовар_ and _самодвижущийся_? Do you mean they are synonyms?

Comment: The connection is that they are both formed by prepending _само_ to a verb describing what the object does.  _самодвижущийся_ is formed similarly, but is not in common usage. No, I don't mean that they are synonyms; those are distinct words, both of which are formed according to the pattern described above.

Comment: First, there's non-zero "самовар" has nothing to do with сам, second, it's indeed not clear what you are asking about.

Comment: @ shabunc "самовар" is literally "self-boil". It definitely has something to do with "сам". Th Op is basically asking when and to what "сам(о)" gets added. Honestly it's just like English "self" or a similar derivative. It's on nouns more often than on adjectival verbs etc.

Comment: Then the Op asks for similar prefixes that get added. Cut some slack, it's not the worst question, boys))

Answer (score 1):

To mention a few:

***гусли-самогуды***

***самострел***

***самопальный***

***самокат***

***самокрутка***

***самокритичность***

***самодурство***

***самомнение***

***самоволка***

***самоход***

***самоубийство***

***самодвижущийся***

***самореклама***

***самопрезентация***

***самодисциплина***

***самовлюблённость***

***самоуверенность***

***самоуважение***

etc. So if we take both 'noun' and 'adjective' as 'nouns' then yes, I think the nouns are more frequent, though we can produce from the list verbs like ***самоуби(ва)ться,*** ***самопрезенто(ва)ться*** and ***самодурствовать,*** of which the latter is the most common and stylistically neutral.

And nearly any word from the list above (which can still be added up with more items) can be transformed into an adjective.

Comment: OK. My point is, we shouldn't encourage asking such unclear questions about nothing, it would be better to make the OP further reformulate the question.

Comment: A value of a question or an answer is determined by an ability to understand it. A question about something you don't understand is not a question 'about nothing', that's my point.

Comment: Anyhow, at this point it's a question about something that's not in the scope of Russian SE. If you can understand the question, will you explain it to me, why the OP says _самовар_ is common and _самодвижущийся_ is uncommon?

Comment: Word-formation and productivity are not in the scope of Russian SE? R U kidding? And the OP states that because OP just studies the Russian, that's why.

Comment: "самопальный", "самодвижущийся" are not nouns

Comment: @user907860 In a case you have missed the definition I use, here it is as it goes in my reply: ...we take both 'noun' and 'adjective' as 'nouns'. Dixi.